# Set fill-column in org-export

Tags: org-export

I am using `org-confluence-export-as-confluence`.  Confluence (when importing markup) seems to treat every newline as a "hard break".

So, I'd like to have the output of `org-confluence-export-as-confluence` output paragraphs without newlines.

I *think* setting `fill-column` to a large value would make that happen, but I can't figure out how to make `org-export-as` use that.

I tried

```
(let ((old-fill (default-value 'fill-column))
    (setq-default fill-column 100000)
    (org-export-to-buffer 'confluence "*org CONFLUENCE Export*"
  async subtreep visible-only body-only ext-plist (lambda () (text-mode)))
  (setq-default fill-column old-fill))
```

but had no luck.

Comment: Some tips: using something like `(let ((fill-column 100000)) ... )` makes more sense and it reads nicer. Also, setting `fill-column` to 0 is equivalent to an infinitely large `fill-column`.

Comment: @nanny Thanks. I had tried the construction you suggested, but when it failed, I realized that binding  `fill-column` wouldn't change the buffer-local value in some buffer created.  If the default value is 70 and I do `(let ((fill-column 5)) (get-buffer-create "foobar"))`, the value of `fill-column` in "foobar" is still 70.

Comment: Yes, because `fill-column` is only 5 while in the `let` block, so if you do `(let ((fill-column 0)) (org-confluence-export-as-confluence))` then it will be 0 while the export function is executing. I think this is a bug with the code you're using to export (ox-confluence). I'm looking at it now.

Comment: @nanny Thank you again.  Indeed, I see the error of my ways.  When I used `eval-expression` to evaluate this `(let ((fill-column 6) (buf (get-buffer-create "foob3"))) (with-current-buffer buf fill-column))` it indeed yielded a value of 6.  I tried `edebug`-ing a little, but couldn't see where things went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My comment was mistaken, `fill-column 0` is not infinite. To make it "infinite" you need to set it to `(point-max)`.

So, in `ox-confluence.el`:

In `org-export-define-derived-backend`, add the line:

```
(paragraph . org-confluence-paragraph)
```

Since `ox-confluence` inherits from `ox-ascii`, I took the paragraph function from `ox-ascii` and changed it to fill strings with a text-width of `(point-max)`:

```
(defun org-confluence-paragraph (paragraph contents info)
  (org-ascii--fill-string
   (if (not (wholenump org-ascii-indented-line-width)) contents
     (concat
      ;; Do not indent first paragraph in a section.
      (unless (and (not (org-export-get-previous-element paragraph info))
                   (eq (org-element-type (org-export-get-parent paragraph))
                       'section))
        (make-string org-ascii-indented-line-width ?\s))
      (replace-regexp-in-string "\\`[ \t]+" "" contents)))
   (point-max) info))
```

Add the above function to `ox-confluence.el`.

This should fix the problem, but I can't find any way to test out Confluence markup, so you'll have to try it yourself.

The reason `fill-column` does nothing here is because `ox-ascii` gets the text widths of paragraphs programmatically, and fills using that value.